# How I Met Your Father: Is 'my soulmate' actually not always synonymous to 'the love of my life' and actually not always romantic?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In HIMYF S01E01: Sophie previously decided to walk the Brooklyn Bridge 'with my soulmate'. Later Sophie walks the Brooklyn Bridge 'without the love of my life'.

[image]

I remember reading before that soulmate doesn't always have a romantic connotation. But I guess in this context soulmate means romantic because Sophie says:

> Sophie: I wanted to tell you, you can't give up on love just because of your proposal fail. I know that there is a Brooklyn Bridge girl out there for you somewhere.
>
> Jesse: Am I supposed to know what that is? Because you look like you practically moved yourself
> to tears just now, but I have no idea what you're talking about.
>
> Sophie: It's this thing I made up. Okay. See, I've lived in New York since college, but I've never walked across the Brooklyn Bridge. And, after a while, I waited so long that I decided I would wait and walk it with my soulmate.

But in general

Is 'my soulmate' actually not always synonymous to 'the love of my life' and actually not always romantic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not watched the show and don't know anything about it, but here is my response:

The term "soulmate" can have different connotations depending on the context and the person using it. In some cases, it is used to refer to a romantic partner, while in other cases it can refer to a close friend, family member, or someone with whom one shares a deep spiritual connection.

In the context of the HIMYF show, the character Sophie is using the term "soulmate" to refer to her romantic partner. She talks about waiting to walk across the Brooklyn Bridge with this person, and she is seen walking across the bridge alone, suggesting that she has not yet found this person.

However, It's worth noting that in general, the phrase "soulmate" is not always synonymous with "the love of my life" and it's not always used in a romantic context. It can be used to describe any person with whom one shares a deep connection, whether romantic or not.

It is also possible for someone to have multiple soulmates, for different aspects of their life, like a romantic soulmate, a friend soulmate, a work soulmate, etc.